# Download Folder Contents from Azure CDN

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cdn

I have a Node.js/Express server running as a Windows service that is created by node-windows (https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows). My newest requirement is to make the server automatically update, and all of the research I have done suggests creating another Windows service that is an UpdaterService.

Whenever an update happens for the original service the updated files are placed in a versioned folder on our Azure CDN. What I need to do is stop the service, retrieve those files from the folder on the CDN, overlay them on the users machine, and restart the service.

I would prefer to do this all in my Node.js/Express environment, but I am also open to other ideas!

Whenever I try to run it I get:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open C:\path\to\service
```

This is the code in my service:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;
// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name: 'orignal-serivce',
  description: 'orignal-serivce',
  script: 'server.js',
});

router.get('/update-manager/:version', function(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const NEW_VERSION: string = req.params.version;
    svc.stop();
    const folderDir = fs.createWriteStream('./');
    const server = https.get(`https://azurecdnurl/${NEW_VERSION}`, (resp) => {
        resp.pipe(folderDir);
        folderDir.on('finish', () => {
            folderDir.close();
            svc.start();
        });
    });
});
```

What I am expecting is to be able to stop the service, download all of the files, overlay the existing files with the new files, and the restart the service.

Like I said I am open to other ideas or even other implementations for the best possible solution here, thanks!